# Nextjs Fetch data when reloading the page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, fetch, next.js

In React we fetch data using `useEffect` when reloading the page:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let ignore = false
  const fetchingData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(<your_path>)
    const data = await res.json()
    if (!ignore) setData(data)
  }; 
  fetchingData()
  return () => { ignore = true }
}, [])
```

But how can I do this in Next.js? Fetch doesn't fire in `getInitialProps` when the page reloads.

Comment: Your question is my answer, thanks.

Comment: @FatemehQasemkhani, my question was based on my incompetence in next.js, later I realized that the problem with axios request in getInitialProps. Glad to help!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Next.js` you usually load data with HTTP requests in `getInitialProps` then you can use them as props:

```
const App = props => (
  <Layout>
  {props.data}
    ...
  </Layout>
);

App.getInitialProps = async function() {
  const res = await fetch(<your_path>)
  const data = await res.json()
  return {
   data
  }
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Looks like it works only on route change but not on page refresh

Comment: When you refresh your page, getInitialProps should still be called. The purpose of your question is to find where/when you should make fetch calls & update your props. I gave you the standard answer: use getInitialProps But if you require to make this call in a component not in a page use componentDidMount

Answer (score 2):

use axios or isomorphic-unfetch. they work both in client and server environments. Fetch API does not exist in the Node.js environment. it. If you still want to use Fetch API in your client-side code, you should use a  isomorphic-unfetch. When you are in the browser, it uses the unfetch polyfill. If your code runs in Node.js, it switches to node-fetch.

```
import "axios" from "axios"

static async getInitialProps(){
    const res=await axios.get('url')//
    const data=res.data
    return {data}
}
```

## UPDATE

In addition to fetch() on the client-side, Next.js polyfills fetch() in the Node.js environment. You can use fetch() in your server code (such as getStaticProps/getServerSideProps) without using polyfills such as isomorphic-unfetch or node-fetch.

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/supported-browsers-features

Comment: I'm not sure about when the update came, but at the time of writing this comment, Next has a polyfill for fetch that works on both the client and the server.

Comment: @dkapur17 you are right. I need to update the answer